# how to reduce grafana rows? (cloudwatch)

Tags: grafana

I use grafana for cloudwatch monitoring

If time range 30m => rows = 146

[image]

If time range 5m => rows = 21

[image]

But I want to row count just one any time range

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Set a period which will cover any your time range, e. g. 3650d

Comment: Thank you!!
Is there a setting where the period can be changed automatically when the time range changes?